# Theming Semantic UI using Create React App - problem with configuration

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have problem with configuration semantic-ui theming in React app created with CRA.

First I'm using clear CSS reference to Semantic UI and everything works fine. But when I decided to configure theming in my app I have a lot of problems.

I make everythink what is writen in this docs (https://react.semantic-ui.com/theming#theming-with-create-react-app) step by step.

My package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "craco eject"
  },

"devDependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^5.6.4",
    "@semantic-ui-react/craco-less": "^1.2.1",
    "semantic-ui-less": "^2.4.1"
}
```

App.js

```
import 'semantic-ui-less/semantic.less';
```

craco.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [{ plugin: require("@semantic-ui-react/craco-less") }],
};
```

theme.config

```
/*******************************
        Theme Selection
*******************************/

/* To override a theme for an individual element
   specify theme name below
*/

/* Global */
@site        : 'default';
@reset       : 'default';

/* Elements */
@button      : 'default';
@container   : 'default';
@divider     : 'default';
@flag        : 'default';
@header      : 'default';
@icon        : 'default';
@image       : 'default';
@input       : 'default';
@label       : 'default';
@list        : 'default';
@loader      : 'default';
@placeholder : 'default';
@rail        : 'default';
@reveal      : 'default';
@segment     : 'default';
@step        : 'default';

/* Collections */
@breadcrumb  : 'default';
@form        : 'default';
@grid        : 'default';
@menu        : 'default';
@message     : 'default';
@table       : 'default';

/* Modules */
@accordion   : 'default';
@checkbox    : 'default';
@dimmer      : 'default';
@dropdown    : 'default';
@embed       : 'default';
@modal       : 'default';
@nag         : 'default';
@popup       : 'default';
@progress    : 'default';
@rating      : 'default';
@search      : 'default';
@shape       : 'default';
@sidebar     : 'default';
@sticky      : 'default';
@tab         : 'default';
@transition  : 'default';

/* Views */
@ad          : 'default';
@card        : 'default';
@comment     : 'default';
@feed        : 'default';
@item        : 'default';
@statistic   : 'default';

/*******************************
            Folders
*******************************/

/* Path to theme packages */
@themesFolder : 'themes';

/* Path to site override folder */
@siteFolder  : '../../src/semantic-ui/site';


/*******************************
         Import Theme
*******************************/

@import (multiple) "~semantic-ui-less/theme.less";
@fontPath : '../../../themes/@{theme}/assets/fonts';

/* End Config */
```

This is my catalog structure

[image]

And all the time I have this problem when I run "npm start":

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\XYX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.8
3 info using node@v10.16.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle lendly@0.1.0~prestart: lendly@0.1.0
6 info lifecycle lendly@0.1.0~start: lendly@0.1.0
7 verbose lifecycle lendly@0.1.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle lendly@0.1.0~start: PATH: C:\Users\XYX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\XYX\Desktop\Frontend\Lendly\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\XYX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\XYX\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\XYX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\XYX\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\XYX\.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.3.4\bin
9 verbose lifecycle lendly@0.1.0~start: CWD: C:\Users\XYX\Desktop\Frontend\Lendly
10 silly lifecycle lendly@0.1.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'craco start' ]
11 silly lifecycle lendly@0.1.0~start: Returned: code: 134  signal: null
12 info lifecycle lendly@0.1.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: lendly@0.1.0 start: `craco start`
13 verbose stack Exit status 134
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\XYX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\XYX\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid lendly@0.1.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\XYX\Desktop\Frontend\Lendly
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\XYX\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v10.16.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.8
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 134
22 error lendly@0.1.0 start: `craco start`
22 error Exit status 134
23 error Failed at the lendly@0.1.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 134, true ]
```